# remove lines that contain some string from another file

Tags: grep

```
grep -v -x -f f2 f1
```

I tried this but not work cause I have

f2:

```
test 141.1.11.1
test2 8.18.8.8
4.4.4.4
```

f1:

```
test 1.1.1.1
test2 8.8.8.8
test3 4.4.4.4
```

The idea is to remove the line `test3 4.4.4.4` because contains `4.4.4.4`, but this is not working. Where is wrong with my command?

It removes when I just typed exactly but not if contains that only 4s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the `-x` option, the use of that is to match the given regex on the exact whole line instead of partially.

```
grep -v -f file2 file1
```

If you want string matching instead of the regular expression matching, as done above, add the `-F` option to the command:

```
grep -v -F -f file2 file1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
mf=[]
k=open ('f2','r')
x=open('f1','r')
for b in x:
    mf.append(b.strip())

co_li=len(mf)

for f in  k:
    for d in range(0,co_li,1):
        if f.strip() in mf[d]:
            print "\n".join( mf[0:d]+mf[d+2:])
```

Tested and worked fine

```
test 1.1.1.1
test2 8.8.8.8

~
```